# In the group $U_{1331}$, determine the number of elements of order 5.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, order-theory, primitive-roots

Please advise whether my solution is correct:

Know: 
$1331 = 11{^3}$ -> Have: $\phi$(11) = 10 -> and 5 | 10

So can use the following theorem: If p is an odd prime and d | (p - 1) . (where d = order of elt. a $\epsilon U_{p}$) Then the number of elements $\epsilon U_{p}$ of order d is $\phi(d)$

In this case: $\phi$(5) = 4. So there are 4 elts. of order 5?

Is this true? Since $1331 = 11{^3}$ -> $\phi$(1331) = $\phi(11)\phi(11)\phi(11)$ = 30 = # of primitive roots?

Also would there be a short cut to determining all these elts. of order 5?

Thanks!

Comment: May I observe that $\phi(11)\phi(11)\phi(11)=10\cdot 10\cdot 10\ne 10+10+10$?

Comment: $\phi$ is multiplicative, but not fully multiplicative. That means that we know that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ (“multiplicative”), but it is not generally the case that $\phi(nm)=\phi(n)\phi(m)$ for arbitrary $n$ and $m$ (“fully multiplicative”). So your claim that $\phi(11^3)=\phi(11)^3$ is incorrect.

Comment: $\phi(11^3)=11^210=1210$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [this article](http://gauss.math.luc.edu/greicius/Math201/Fall2012/Lectures/units-structure.article.pdf) helpful.

Since $\varphi(1331) = \varphi(11^3) = 11^3-11^2 = 1331 - 121 = 1210$, it follows that $|U_{1331}|=1210$.

Acording to Wolfram alpha

$$2^{\text{Divisors}[1210]} \pmod{1331}
  =\{2, 4, 32, 1024, 717, 323, 362, 606, 596, 1170, 1330, 1\}$$

It follows that $U_{1331}=\langle \bar 2 \rangle$

Hence there are $\varphi(5) = 4$ elements of  $U_{1331}$ of order $5$.

Those elements would be

\begin{align}
   2^{1\cdot 242} \mod{1331} &= 1170 \\
   2^{2\cdot 242} \mod{1331} &= 632 \\
   2^{3\cdot 242} \mod{1331} &= 735 \\
  2^{4\cdot 242} \mod{1331} &= 124
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

First, $\phi$ is not fully multiplicative; in particular, it is. *not* true that $\phi(11^3)=\phi(11)^3$ (and also, $10\times10\times10=1000$, not $30$, but that is irrelevant). The function $\phi$ is *multiplicative*: if $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$; but not fully multiplicative.

Second, for $p$ an odd prime, the group $U(p^n)$ of units modulo $p^n$ is known to be cyclic. If you know this fact, then you can use it, because in a cyclic group, there is one and only one subgroup of order $d$ for any $d$ that divides the order. So there is one and only one subgroup of order $5$ in $U(11^3)$ if and only if $5|\phi(11^3)$ (otherwise, there are none). And how many elements of order $5$ are there, then?

Comment: Oh okay, thank you for your response! So, I believe the answer is 0 then?

Comment: @user711963 I would review your calculations if I were you.

Comment: sorry. 5 | $phi(11{^3}$ = 242?

Comment: Oh correction again. It's 4 i think. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors.

First, there  can be no element of order $5$ in a group of order $1331$, since $5$ is not a divisor of $1331$ (think of Lagrange's theorem).

Second, for any prime $p$, and any $n>0$, $\;\varphi(p^n)=p^{n-1}(p-1)$, so $\;\varphi(1331)=1210$.

Comment: $U_n$ is a standard notation for the group of units in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$. I'm rather sure that's the notation used here, so $U_{1331}$ would have order $10\cdot 11^2 = 1210$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I thought it was here the group of roots of unity in the complex plane (which also uses this notation).

Comment: No, no, that's totally impossible. There never was and never will be ambiguous notation in mathematics. (Although I'm more used to $E(n)$ for the roots of unity, now you mention it I recall that I also know the $U_n$ notation.)

Comment: For me, the units in $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ are usually denoted $(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)^\times$. And $U(1)$ is the group of complex numbers with modulus $1$…

Comment: The invokation of $\phi$ strongly suggests the use refers to the units modulo $n$; this is the notation in several introductory Abstract Algebra books; if I recall correctly, Dummit and Foote use it.

Answer (score 1):

$x\in (\mathbb Z/1331\mathbb Z)^\times$ has order $5$ iff $x^5\equiv1\bmod1331$ and $x\not\equiv1\bmod1331$.

$x^5\equiv1\bmod1331=11^3\implies x^5\equiv1\bmod11$.

$2$ is a primitive root modulo $11$ because $2^5=32=33-1\equiv-1\bmod11$.

Therefore, the four residue classes $2^2=4$, $2^4=16\equiv5$, $2^6=64\equiv9$, and $2^8\equiv(2^4)^2\equiv25\equiv3$

have order $5\bmod11$.

We can "lift" these solutions to $\mod 121$; e.g., for the solution $4^5\equiv1\bmod11$ we have

$(4+11k)^5\equiv1\bmod121\implies4^5+5\times4^4\times11k\equiv1\bmod121$

$\implies11\times93+1+5\times4^4\times11k\equiv1\bmod121\implies93+5\times256k\equiv0\bmod11$

$\implies5(1+3k)\equiv0\bmod11\implies3k\equiv-1\bmod11\implies k\equiv7\bmod11.$

So $(4+77)^5=81^5\equiv1\bmod 121$.

Similarly, $5$ lifts to $27^5\equiv1\bmod121$, $9$ lifts to $9\bmod121$, and $3$ lifts to $3$.

(Alternatively, in retrospect, $3^5=243\equiv1\bmod 121$,

so $3^2=9$, $3^3=27$, and $3^4=81$ also have order $5$ mod $121$.)

Now these four solutions can be lifted to solutions $\bmod 1331$.

Take $x\equiv3\bmod121$ and set $(3+121k)^5\equiv1\bmod1331$.

Then $3^5+5\times3^4121k\equiv1\bmod1331\implies2+5\times3^4k\equiv0\bmod11$

$\implies2+5\times4k\equiv0\implies2+9k\equiv0\implies k\equiv1\bmod11$,

so $124^5\equiv1\bmod1331$.

Similarly, $9$ lifts to $735$, $27$ lifts to $632$, and $81$ lifts to $1170$.

These are the four elements of order $5$ in $(\mathbb Z/1331\mathbb Z)^\times.$

Comment: My answer agrees with that of [steven gregory](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/75410/steven-gregory) but does not rely on knowledge that $2$ is a primitive root mod $1331$ and calculating high powers of it